# How can i add loading when my work is in progress

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a activity with a button on it.

When i click on button it takes some times to the progress do it job.Some time more than 20 second. I want a loading or other thing like that to show to user when button work does not finished.
How can i do that? thank you.

Comment: Did you google? "Android progress dialog"

Comment: use asynctask class.

Comment: plz google it before asking , anyway check this http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setTitle("Processing...");
        pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            //Do something...
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (pd!=null) {
            pd.dismiss();
            b.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

};
task.execute((Void[])null);
```

Comment: this is a perfect answer